# Why Spring MVC transform parameter [""] to [null] during mapping json to java bean?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I want to know why spring mvc transform [""] to [null] when I use PostMan to test my API.
here is my controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<Object> participateRstActivities(
        HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody RstActivityFrom rstForm)
        throws ServiceException {
          log.info("list size:{}, frist object:{}",rstForm.getRestaurant_ids().size(), rstForm.getRestaurant_ids().get(0));
        }
```

here is my java bean:

```
public class RstActivityFrom {

    private List<Integer> restaurant_ids;
    private int activity_id;
    // omit getter & setter
}
```

here is my request body when I use postman to test my api:

```
{
 "restaurant_ids":[""],
 "activity_id":119129
}
```

and the log in controller print :
list size:1, frist object:null.

this problem makes me feel confuse, I want to know why. Thanks

Comment: When you debug, do you see the rstForm.activity_id is set?

Comment: I believe that since you declare restaurant_ids as a List<Integer> then you json should not be an array of String ([""]), but should just be empty ([])

Comment: activity_id is correct, only restaurant_ids is transformed to [null], I don't know why I send [""] to a Integer list,  no throwing error , and transform to [null]

Comment: So that solved your issue?

Comment: I know parameter [""] is uncorrect for Integer list and it will not happened under normal circumstances. But tester report a bug for this, so I want to know why spring mvc transform [""] to [null] instead of throwing an error. Thank you~~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since restaurant_ids is a List and not String, Change your JSON for restaurant_ids:

```
{
 "restaurant_ids":[],
 "activity_id":119129
}
```

If you don't want to allow an empty String value for objects mapped from your JSON, you can look into setting the Jackson's ObjectMapper Features as described here:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html

The Java API for Jackson's DeserializationConfig.Feature(s) can be found here:

http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/1.9/org/codehaus/jackson/map/DeserializationConfig.Feature.html